# How do I access a task output variable in Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use the new multistage yaml pipelines to download an artifact from a specific build.  The `DownloadBuildArtifacts@0` task has an output variable for `BuildNumber` that I would like to reference further on, but I can't figure out how to access it.

In the GUI for the task there is a box that let's you set a reference name
[image]

But from the yaml pipeline definition I can't figure out how access this variable.

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: 'Sandbox'
    pipeline: 'bash-testing'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'someArtifactName'
    referenceNames: 'blahblah'
- bash: echo $BLAHBLAH_BUILDNUMBER
```

Simply outputs

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You set an incorrect output variable defined.

The format of define an output variable in previous task in YAML:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;isOutput=true]this is the value of output variable"
name: PWS
```

**Note**: `isOutput=true` is the **key code** which announce this variable is an output variable. And also, `name` is equals to `Reference name` which displayed in Classic editor UI.

[image]

For how to access and use this output variable in Bash task, the format of this call script is:

```
echo $(name.VariableName)
```

So, for my sample script is:

```
echo $(PWS.myOutputVar)
```

Comment: wouldn't that cause the variable "PWS.myOutputVar" to appear in task group parameter list?

Answer (score 9):

My yaml was incorrect and Merlin Liang's comment about `name` being the right syntax helped me figure it out.

The correct yaml syntax needed to reference a task output variable is.

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: 'Sandbox'
    pipeline: 'bash-testing'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'some-artifact-name'
  name: 'TEST'
- bash: echo $(TEST.BuildNumber)
```